# Angular RxJs BehaviorSubject not updating properly

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to share a string value from sibling components(light-switch to navbar). My problem is that the property `themeColor` is not getting updated when I emit the new value from my DataService.

Here is my structure for my App.Component.html:

```
<navbar></navbar>
<banner><light-switch></light-switch></banner>
```

I'm trying to use a DataService:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private themeColor = new BehaviorSubject<string>("#f5f0f0");
  currentThemeColor = this.themeColor.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeThemeColor(color: string) {
    this.themeColor.next(color)
  }

}
```

This is my light-switch.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from "./../Services/DataService";

@Component({
  selector: 'light-switch',
  templateUrl: './light-switch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./light-switch.component.scss']
})
export class LightSwitchComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentTheme;
  public themeColor;

  constructor(private sanitization: DomSanitizer, private dataService: DataService) { 
    this.currentTheme = "dark";
    this.themeColor = "#f5f0f0";
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.currentThemeColor.subscribe(color =>{ this.themeColor = color});
  }

  changeToLight(){
    this.dataService.changeThemeColor("black");
  }
  changeToDark(){
    this.dataService.changeThemeColor("#f5f0f0");
  }
}
```

And my navbar.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from "./../Services/DataService";

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: './navigation-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation-bar.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationBar implements OnInit {
  private themeColor;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.currentThemeColor.subscribe(color => {this.themeColor = color});
  }
}
```

NavigationBar.html:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <i class="fa fa-github bannerIcon" id="githubIcon" [style.color]='themeColor'></i>
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin bannerIcon" id="linkedInIcon" [style.color]='themeColor'></i>
</div>
```

Light-switch.html:

```
<div id="lightSwitch">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary switchBtn-on" (click)="changeToLight()">On</button>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary switchBtn-off">Off</button>
</div>
```

I have DataService as a provider in my App.Module.ts. When `ngOnInit` runs in navbar.ts, it does get the default value I set and when I call the `changeThemeColor()` in light-switch.ts, it does go into DataService.ts and change the `currentColor` property, but again, the `themeColor` property in navbar.ts does not update to that `currentColor` property. I suspect there is some sort of event listener I need to correctly get the value from DataService to navbar, but I thought that's what I subscribed for.

Comment: Your code looks basically correct. Is it possible your DataService is not correctly registered and you aren't getting a singleton? Is the providers array for your DataService in a module? Or a component? Or in multiple components?

Comment: My providers array is in App.Module.ts like so: `providers:[DataService]`

Comment: I'm with @DeborahK here, your code looks OK, there may be something wrong with your modules. Please, search for `DataService` through your codebase and find where it is provided. There may be more than once and you could have missed it. Also, can you share html of your components? (navbar and light-switch)

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, DeborahK That was the problem. I had DataService as a provider in a different component and as soon as I got rid of that, the value updated on navbar. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that fixed it for you! I'll copy my comment into an answer so we can close this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code looks basically correct.

Is it possible your DataService is not correctly registered and you aren't getting a singleton? Is the providers array for your DataService in a module? Or a component? Or in multiple components?

Ensure the service is only registered (added to the providers array) in one place.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Banged my head against the wall for too long.  Why can't a service be registered as a provider for every component that needs it?

Comment: You can ... but then every component gets its own instance of that service. In many cases, that is not what was intended. But in some cases you may want to have separate instances of the service. For example, if you are building a reusable component, say a search page, and you want to have two of them on one parent page (search for movies, search for actors). Registering the provider in the component means each instance of the search component can track it's own state (last search) without them "sharing" or overwriting each other. Make sense?

Comment: That is one nice observation! Thanks, for the explanation. This has been of real help.

Comment: I have the same scenario probably, module have some components and every component listen to service subjects which registered at this module providers array, and one shell component updates the subjects, API calls are done but UI/subjects not updated, module providers work at some components only tried add to components providers array but still after hassles unfurently removed this service from the module and provided it at the root then all works, IDK how!

Comment: Appreciating this answer that gave me a solution after 6hrs of debugging.

Answer (score 3):

1 - If your data service is included in some other module ,for eg: Shared Module which is imported in your App Module , then try to move the service in App module so that all components should share one instance of the service and can update the state of the data.

2- If it is used inside a component then it will have different instance only for that specific component.

In both cases the instances are not singleton and hence the data state update is not notified in other components/ modules.
For this problem , you need to have a global service instance. So, include the DataService in your App module provider array.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to use

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'})
```

in order to load the service on the root.